# How to select only 1 row per unique field (with another field determining which in case of duplicates)

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, greatest-n-per-group

I've looked around for a while, and I'm not really sure whether I need some sort of IF statement, LIMIT statement, or something completely different.

**SITUATION**

I have a database that looks something like this:

```
id    |   elem_id   |  elem_data  | draft
1     |  uniq1234   |  examplestr |   0
2     |  uniq1653   |  examplestr |   1
3     |  uniq9964   |  examplestr |   0
4     |  uniq1234   |  examplestr |   1
```

And so on and so forth...

**My Intent**

I want to select only one row for every unique `elem_id`. Where two exist, I want to select the one that has a draft value of 1. (So, for a query on the above table it would find two occurrences of the elem_id `uniq1234` and select the one with the draft value of 1 (that is, row 4)).

Comment: Use `WHERE draft = MAX(draft)` and group by `elem_id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  elem_ID, MAX(`Draft`) maxDraft
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY elem_ID
        ) b ON a.elem_ID = b.elem_ID AND
                a.`draft` = b.maxDraft
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/774f7/1)

Comment: To guarantee that you return only one row per `elem_ID`, you would need some sort of guarantee that there won't be two (or more) rows that had the same maximum value of `Draft` for a given `elem_ID`. (Otherwise, this query can return more than one row for each `elem_ID`.)

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a quick answer! I'll accept as soon as possible (it says I still have to wait 5 min.)

Comment: @spencer7593: JW is right--I will never have more than 2 rows per elem_id. At most, one with a draft value of 1 and one with a draft value of 0.

Comment: I didn't say anything about "sorting". I was speaking to the specification that ONE row be returned; and that the query is depending on a unique max value of `Draft` for `elem_ID`. We also might need to consider (in a more general case) of the possibility of single row for `elem_ID` that has a NULL value in the `Draft` column. This query will not return that row either.

Comment: @spencer7593 yeah, previous comment was deleted. this query will not return more than one record of `elem_ID`, i can guarantee that. in this case, *i think*, column draft is not *nullable*

Comment: You're right, in this case draft has a default value of 0. In regards to the other issue (though as I mentioned it won't be a problem for me) it does seem to return multiple '1' rows if they exist http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56ede/1

Comment: @Pete: The purpose of my comment was for future readers. My purpose was to indicate that for this solution to be viable, you need some sort of guarantee about the contents of the table. You have that guarantee, that the values in the table will be such that this query  is guaranteed to return the specified resultset. (Other than the limited example data in your question, there is no indication that the the `Draft` column will not be NULL, and that `(elem_ID,Draft)` is unique, or even that `1` is the maximum value in the `Draft` column.)

Comment: Gotcha, point taken. I am curious about how to enforce the single row per elem_id. Can this by done by modifying the current statement? or would it have to be a completely different approach?

Comment: Add unique constraint. Try this: ALTER TABLE tableName ADD CONSTRAINT tb_UQ UNIQUE(elem_id, draft)

Comment: If you execute that there will be a unique draft for every elem_id

Answer (score -2):

If you are only selecting 1 row in total, you can do this with `ORDER` magic

```
SELECT
  id,
  elem_id,
  elem_data,
  draft
FROM your_table
WHERE elem_id = 'uniq1234'
ORDER BY draft DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If you want to get multiple rows in the result, group by the `elem_id` to get the max draft, then nest that subquery

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.elem_id,
  a.elem_data,
  a.draft
FROM your_table a,
(SELECT
   b.elem_id,
   MAX(b.draft) as m
 FROM your_table b
 GROUP BY b.elem_id) sub
WHERE a.elem_id = sub.elem_id
  AND a.draft = sub.m
```

Comment: don't use `LIMIT` it will only return number of records equal to the value supplied in the `LIMIT`

Comment: @JW. Yeah that's the idea. I left off the WHERE clause in that query, it would work if you knew which elem_id you were looking for, just didn't know if it had a draft or not